# jQuery - Loading content from loaded content - .load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to load specific information from individual product links after they have been loaded in.

**What I have and what it does:**

```
$(function(){
    $('.prdContainer .prdHero').each(function(i){
        $(this).load(('http://www.domain.com .product:nth-child(' + (i + 1)+ ') .productMainImage'), function(){
            $('.prdContainer .prdDesc').each(function(){
                var prdLink = $('.prdHero .productMainImage').attr('href');

                $(this).load(prdLink + ' ' + '.productHeading');
            });
        });
    });
});
```

1 - Function loads the product into .prdHero - 3x

2 - Function gets link and adds to new .load

3 - This should then load in the heading specific to the product but all 3 are loading in the same headings (the first).

I feel like I need to make my function specific to .prdContainer and use $(this), I'm just not sure how?

Comment: probably `$(this).find(".prdHero .productMainImage").attr("href")` or something like that.

Comment: what are the specific elements represented by your selectors? A rough html outline would help

Comment: so many loads....Is there not a better solution that does not make so many Ajax calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the specific HTML being shown I have to guess your hierarchy, but something like this will use a known parent element as the start point of each search:

```
$(function(){
    $('.prdContainer .prdHero').each(function(i){
        var $parent = $(this).closest('.prdContainer');
        $(this).load(('http://www.domain.com .product:nth-child(' + (i + 1)+ ') .productMainImage'), function(){
            $parent.find('.prdDesc').each(function(){
                var prdLink = $parent.find('.prdHero .productMainImage').attr('href');
                $(this).load(prdLink + ' ' + '.productHeading');
            });
        });
    });
});
```

*As mentioned in comment, you seem to have way too many Ajax calls going on. Perhaps showing the overall problem will result in a better solution?*

Comment: Thanks for your help with this!  Your changes work exactly as expected.  I'll run you through my code here: http://jsfiddle.net/64556vus/  You're probably right, I'm more than likely making too many calls.  Really new to Ajax so I'm not too confident I'm doing it the best way!!  Any input would be great though :)

Comment: For a production site, I would combine multiple results into single requests (at the very least the product details with the product summary). Your biggest overhead to avoid is a large number of small requests. Better to have a few large requests.